# For a selected file Power Automate - Trigger date

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I was wondering how does the trigger date works in "for a selected file" in the power automate.

When I select "Date" from Add an input and Save. Later, When I select future date from SharePoint on "Trigger date" I end up getting email immediately.

My complete flow updated below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you adding any condition based on trigger date before sending an email? If you are adding email action directly without any check, it will obviously send an email immediately.

Comment: Not really ! I am using the trigger date now. How would that condition looks like for trigger date. Do we have any suggestions on that ?

Comment: As per my understanding, you are manually entering "Trigger date", right? So in power automate it's just a variable. Now, you if you want to send an email after the set date, you have to pause your flow until that date & then add send an email action.

Comment: Yes, i am entering date manually on SharePoint on Selected folder. I have updated my question above with complete flow.

Comment: What is the use of trigger date variable here? Do you want to send an email after the mentioned trigger date?

Comment: Yes, Sometimes i want to send immediately and sometimes on preferred date.

Comment: When you want to send email immediately >> write email action. When you want to send email after "specific date" >> use pause until action to pause your flow until specified date >> after this action write send an email action.

Comment: Yes, you can define it in single flow if you know how the condition when to send email immediately and when to send preferred date. You can use "Condition" action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For a selected file` trigger fires either immediately or after a very short delay. **Always**. So, just because you added a date field and called it "Trigger date" does not change this fact.

[image]

So, the `Trigger date` name of the field is misleading. Your flow actually *still* triggers immediately. It might just wait for the specified date.

So, after your flow is triggered, it can delay until the specified date and *then* send an email. But for this whole time it will be in a "running" state. In order to do it, use the `Delay until` action:

[image]

Comment: In addition, is it possible to add time with date ?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a control for picking date and time. just date

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful !